# Really can't understand why my program isn't working

Tags: occam-pi

I've really spent a lot of time working at this problem and googling around to find a solution, but I can't seem to find what's wrong.

I've learning how to code occam and have the following program:

```
PROC light (CHAN OF BYTE screen, CHAN OF INT light.change)
  INT light.on :
  WHILE TRUE
    SEQ
      light.change ? light.on
      IF
        light.on = 1
          screen ! 'y'
        TRUE
          SKIP
:

PROC test(CHAN OF BYTE keyboard, scr)
  CHAN OF INT to.light :
  INITIAL INT on IS 1(INT) :
  BYTE b :
  SEQ
    light(scr, to.light)
    WHILE TRUE
      SEQ
        keyboard ? b
        IF
          b = 'o'
            to.light ! on
          TRUE
            SKIP
:
```

All I'm trying to do is communicate from one process to another when I press the '**`o`**' key.

The error message I'm getting from the (KR*o*C) compiler is:

```
Error at lift.occ:11
Program failed, state = e, eflags = 00000000
```

which is the `light.on = 1` line.

As far as I can see, the **`light`** <kbd>`PROC`</kbd> will wait for some input on its **`light.change`** <kbd>`channel`</kbd> and will then assign it to its **`light.on`** <kbd>`variable`</kbd>. The program will then proceed to a conditional statement **`IF`**, where the `light.on = 1` line should in this case evaluate to **`true`**. But instead I get this error.

I have tried using the **`-verbose`** flag, but the compiler says that you can't use it for .occ files.

**Does anyone know how or if I can get more detailed info from the compiler?**

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code compiles for me and when run reaches deadlock

```
james:conc$ occbuild --program light.occ 
james:conc$ light
KRoC: deadlock: no valid processes found in workspace(s)

KRoC: program deadlocked (no processes to run)
```

I can also get it to run in verbose mode as below

```
occbuild -v --program light.occ
```

On a different note you might want to change your structure. Try having three PROC's

```
PROC is.light.on(CHAN BYTE screen! , CHAN INT light.control)
  WHILE TRUE
...output to terminal if light is on or off

PROC light.switch(CHAN BYTE keyboard? , CHAN INT light.control)
  WHILE TRUE
...use the keyboard to turn light on and off

PROC light(CHAN BYTE keyboard? , screen!)
  CHAN INT light.control:--0 for light on;1 for light off
  PAR
    light.switch(keyboard? , light.control!)
    is.light.on(screen! , light.control?)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I appreciate it. I'm going to have to wait until tomorrow to try it out.